# Nodejs - TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

I am running node-js with typescript project, I am getting the below error while running project.

```
C:\Users\Projects\api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:307
        throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
              ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
src\app.ts (12,13): This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof e' has no call signatures. (2349)
src\app.ts (24,22): Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'. (2339)
src\app.ts (32,13): Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'. (2339)
    at getOutput (C:\Users\mysystem\Projects\myProject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:307:15)
    at C:\Users\mysystem\Projects\myProject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:336:16
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\mysystem\Projects\myProject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:498:11)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\mysystem\Projects\myProject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:392:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\mysystem\Projects\myProject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:395:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

This is my configuration.

node - 17.3.0

typescript -4.6.4

yarn - v1.22.15

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import * as morgan from "morgan";
import { Routes } from "./routes";
import { validationResult } from "express-validator";

function handleError(err, _req, res, _next) {
  res.status(err.statusCode || 500).send(err.message);
}

const app = express();
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Routes.forEach((route) => {
  (app as any)[route.method](
    route.route,
    ...route.validation,
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
      try {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const result = await new (route.controller as any)()[route.action](
          req,
          res,
          next
        );
        res.json(result);
      } catch (err) {
        next(err);
      }
    }
  );
});

app.use(handleError);

export default app;
```

This setup is working in other system. This error occurs in only my system.

It looks like the error is from ts-node package, I tried reinstalling the package, clearing cache etc. but still the error occurs. Other system has same versions as my system, and it works there

Comment: Can you share some code? The error seems to be in src/app.ts.

Comment: That is a type error. Typescript thinks your code is doing something that should not be allowed. But since you have not shown any of the code causing the problem, we cannot possibly help you fix it. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Until you provide more info here, there's nothing we can do help you.